# Type of a function with Implicit parameters in Scala

Tags: scala, implicit, currying, higher-order-functions

I would like to have a higher order function that takes in parameter a function that accepts a specific implicit parameter.

To be more precise, I am trying to make a function that takes a `Future` creation method that depends on an implicit context and returns a method that doesn't depend on the context.

To be more concrete, let's say that I have something like this:

```
def foo(a: Int)(implicit ctx: ExecutionContext): Future[Float] = future { somelongBar... }
```

I would like to do have a method like this:

```
def provideCtx[A](func: ExecutionContext => A): A = {
     val ctx = setupCtx
     func(ctx)
}
```

but if I call `provideCtx(foo)`, the compiler complains about the implicit execution context missing.

The fact that I am dealing with an ExecutionContext is not very important. What I would like to find is how to write the parameter type to accept a function with an implicit argument of a specific type. I understand that the implicit part is a curryed argument, so that in fact I have a function like so: `ExecutionContext => Int => Future[Float]`, and I am pretty sure that at runtime, the jvm doesn't know that that ExecutionContext is implicit, but I can't make the compiler understand that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `foo` is a method, not a function, and eta-expansion (which converts methods to functions) is not attempted until after implicit application. See section 6.26.2 of the language specification for the details, and [this issue](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3781) for additional discussion.

One workaround would be to write something like this:

```
provideCtx((ctx: ExecutionContext) => (a: Int) => foo(a)(ctx))
```

I'm not sure a more generic solution is possible (at least without some kind of reflection, etc.), since we can't even refer to `foo` (except in a method call, of course) without an implicit in scope.

Comment: indeed, I ended up writing something very similar right now, it's just a bit cumbersome.