# How to obtain a partial applied function with implicit parameters

Tags: scala

Here is a function with implicit parameters :

> def maxF(implicit i1: Int, implicit i2: Int) = i1 + i2

How to obtain a partial applied function `maxF _` . If you write `val f = maxF _`,  it complain `error: could not find implicit value for parameter i1: Int` .

Any suggestiong ?

Comment: You can't get different values with implicit parameters of the same type.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18635935/334519). The problem is that eta expansion doesn't happen until after the implicit parameters have been applied.