# Obtaining array element in Scala works only with explicit apply method

Tags: arrays, scala

Accessing collection elements in Scala is done by `apply` method. Having said that I tried to read numbers from standard input and get the second one as int in just one line.

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val number = StdIn.readLine().split(" ").map(_.toInt)(1)
  }
```

IntelliJ marks this `1` and show the error (the same is shown after the compilation attempt):

> Error:(11, 60) type mismatch;  found   : Int(1)  required:
>   scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Array[String],Int,?]
>       val number = StdIn.readLine().split(" ").map(_.toInt)(1)

Folding the expression in the parentheses dosn't help as well. However, when I split mapping input to int array and getting the element to other lines, everything works fine.

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val numbers = StdIn.readLine().split(" ").map(_.toInt)
    numbers(1)
  }
```

The explicit invocation of `apply` also does the job:

```
val number = StdIn.readLine().split(" ").map(_.toInt).apply(1)
```

Why does this weird behaviour happens? Obtaining element via `array(5)` is just a shortcut for `array.apply(5)`, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As compiler already pointed out, `map` is defined with two arg lists. second one containing a single implicit param: `implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]`

For a vast majority of scenarios, the users don't worry about specifying the second arg. Specifically, in your case this is what the compiler "figures out":

```
StdIn.readLine().split(" ").map(_.toInt)(Array.canBuildFrom[Int])
```

So, if writing out `apply` is not desired then the following is the only choice:

```
StdIn.readLine().split(" ").map(_.toInt)(Array.canBuildFrom[Int])(1)
```

---

It's a bit counter-intuitive that adding a set of parentheses still doesn't quite do the trick:

```
( StdIn.readLine().split(" ").map(_.toInt) )(1)  //does not compile, same error
```

Perhaps it's best to demonstrate what's going with a simpler example. Consider the following function:

```
def add(x:Int)(y:Int) = x + y
```

The type of `add(2)` is `Int => Int` (since we haven't specified `y`). Note that adding a set of parentheses around it doesn't change the return type, i.e. `(add(2))` still has a type `Int => Int`. Similarly, `(Array("1").map(_.toInt))(1)` still requires an instance of `CanBuildFrom` before using shorthand for `apply`.

---

Suggested reading about Scala collections:

- [The Architecture of Scala Collections](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/architecture-of-scala-collections.html)
- [Getting to know CanBuildFrom (without a PhD)](http://blog.bruchez.name/2012/08/getting-to-know-canbuildfrom-without-phd.html)

and implicit scope:

- [Scala Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/07-implicits.html) <- as comprehensive as it gets
- [Where does Scala look for implicits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits)

Comment: The thing that's mysterious (at least to me) is why does `val number = (StdIn.readLine().split(" ").map(_.toInt))(1)` not work?  The search for the implicit parameter extends outside the parentheses as if they are not there.  I can't find an explanation in the Scala spec.

Comment: @JoePallas updated my answer, hopefully that clears up the confusion.

Comment: the updated answer opens a can of worms because I'm not sure we can talk about the type of `add(2)` without doing the explicit eta-expansion `add(2) _`.  And it looks like that's where part of the confusion comes from: implicit resolution occurs before eta-expansion (http://stackoverflow.com/a/18635935/3851755).  Interestingly, that leads to an alternative solution: `(StdIn.readLine().split(" ").map(_.toInt) _)(1)`

Comment: @JoePallas sure, on its own `add(2)` is not a valid expression, e.g. `val x = add(2)` will not compile. however, i'm referring to `add(2)` as a smaller part of bigger expression. the point i'm trying to make is `add(2)(3)` is the same as `(add(2))(3)` is the same as `((add(2)))(3)` and so on... the second arg list must be known *before* using shorthand for `apply` since the invocation of `apply` is done on the *result of the expression*. i.e. invoking `apply` using shorthand notation clashes with explicit specification of the second arg list...

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a collision with an implicit argument to `map`.  This is one of the cases apply needs to be invoked explicitly.

Here's some REPL that replicates the error:

```
scala> class Foo {
  def apply() { println("bar") }
}

scala> def makeFoo(): Foo = new Foo

scala> makeFoo()()
bar // got the println from the apply here

scala> def makeFooImplicit()(implicit x: Int): Foo = new Foo

scala> implicit val x = 5

scala> makeFooImplicit()()
  <console>:11: error: not enough arguments for method makeFooImplicit:(implicit x: Int)Foo.
  Unspecified value parameter x.
          makeFooImplicit()()
```

Comment: So how to invoke `makeFooImplicit`?

Comment: @BartłomiejSzałach both `makeFooImplicit()` and `makeFooImplicit()(1)` will return an instance of `Foo`. the former works because `implicit val x = 5` is defined which effectively means `makeFooImplicit()(5)`.

Comment: You could say `val f = makeFooImplicit(); f()` and get the printout.